# Is that possible using user-defined notification sound for iPhone with screen locked?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I am an iOS developer , my team planning to develop a alarm application , which user could select our customised ringtone from our app ,set the time for the alarm ,  then lock iPhone . Is that possible when the alarm time is reached , iPhone could play our customised ringtone ?

I appreciate for any advices , thanks!

Comment: @Fogmeister said it, use `UILocalNotification`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you would have to use `UILocalNotification` this will fire at a given time after being created.

[Read the UILocalNotification documentation here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/)

There is a property on the class called `soundName` this name can be the name of a sound file embedded in your project and will play when the notification fires.

Comment: Thx Fogmeister ,you helped me a lot :)

Comment: @Fogmeister broken link...can you fix that?